# Apply a function across numpy matrix row and concatenate the result?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I tried to use `numpy.apply_along_axis`, but this seems to work only when the applied function collapses the dimension and not when it expands it.

Example:

```
def dup(x):
    return np.array([x, x])
a = np.array([1,2,3])
np.apply_along_axis(dup, axis=0, arr=a) # This doesn't work
```

I was expecting the matrix below (notice how its dimension has expanded from the input matrix `a`):

```
np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
```

In R, this would be accomplished by the `**ply` set of functions from the `plyr` package. How to do it with `numpy`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to repeat the elements you can use `np.repeat` :

```
>>> np.repeat(a,2).reshape(3,2)
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

And for apply a function use `np.frompyfunc` and for convert to an integrate array use `np.vstack`:

```
>>> def dup(x):
...     return np.array([x, x])
>>> oct_array = np.frompyfunc(dup, 1, 1)
>>> oct_array(a)
array([array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])], dtype=object)
>>> np.vstack(oct_array(a))
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

Comment: `np.frompyfunc` seems like the solution! Just curious, do you know what the name stands for?

Comment: @Heisenberg Do you mean the name `frompyfunc`?

Comment: Yes. `frompyfunc` to what? And what is `pyfunc`?

Comment: Its just a name means from a python function! maybe to a numpy object :)

Comment: probably stands for "create a numpy array from a python function", i.e. a general python function, as opposed to a built in numpy function

Answer (score 1):

For someone used to general Python code, a list comprehension may be the simplest approach:

```
In [20]: np.array([dup(x) for x in a])
Out[20]: 
array([[1, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [3, 3]])
```

The comprehension (a loop or mapping that applies `dup` to each element of `a`) returns `[array([1, 1]), array([2, 2]), array([3, 3])]`, which is easily turned into a 2d array with `np.array()`.

At least for this small `a`, it is also faster than the `np.frompyfunc` approach.  The `np.frompyfunc` function will give full access to broadcasting, but evidently it doesn't apply any fast iteration tricks.

`apply_along_axis` can help keep indices straight when dealing with many dimensions, but it still is just an iteration method.  It's written Python so you can study its code yourself.  It is much more complicated than needed for this simple case.

Answer (score 0):

In order for your example to work as expected, `a` should be 2-dimensional:

```
def dup(x):
    # x is now an array of size 1
    return np.array([ x[0], x[0] ])
a = np.array([[1,2,3]])  # 2dim
np.apply_along_axis(dup, axis=0, arr=a)
=> 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Of course, you probably want to transpose the result.